# JavaMail IMAP not using specified properties

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, imap

I'm seeing an issue where when connected to a mailbox using IMAP the infinite timeout default is causing an issue. I am having an issue getting Java Mail to recgonise IMAP properties. I verified IMAP did not seem to be using the properties by setting things like port number to the value 1, which should not work.

This is the code snippit:

```
Properties props = new Properties()
props.put("mail.imap.port", "1");
props.put("mail.imap.timeout", "1");
props.put("mail.imaps.connectiontimeout", "1");
Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
store.connect(***,***,***);
```

If anyone knows where the problem is arising from that would great, all help is appreciated.

Comment: what happens if you do a `props.contains("mail.imap.timeout")` and if it is there a `props. getProperty("mail.imap.timeout")`?

Comment: I didnt try the above, I found the solution to the problem just now, which was, changing: Store store = session.getStore("imaps"); to Store store = session.getStore("imap");

SIGH

Answer (score 0):

I believe  you should be using `props.setProperty(key, value)` instead of using `props.put(key, value)`.  The documentation here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html warns you not to use hashTable methods

Comment: Yes I should be doing that, it wasn't the problem though, the problem was: 

I didnt try the above, I found the solution to the problem just now, which was, changing: Store store = session.getStore("imaps"); to Store store = session.getStore("imap");

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're using the "imaps" protocol but setting properties for the "imap" protocol.  Change your property names to "mail.imaps.*".

Comment: Marked as the answer as it is an improvement on what I had mentioned. Thank you.